# How can I find the project file mentioned in this answer?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am having trouble changing the language version in my C# project using Visual Studio 2019.

I searched around for a solution to my problem and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65139431/1777374) on Stack Overflow.

How can I find the project file mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is named `your-project-name.csproj`.
It will be found in your project's folder.

If you're unsure where is located the folder, right-click your project
and select "Open Folder in File Explorer".

Comment: It's surprising to me that I couldn't open this file for editing directly in Visual Studio, but your solution got me where I needed to be nonetheless. Thank you.